# how can we use __construct() variables in php 7

Tags: php, php-7

constructors features is deprecated in PHP 7.0.x, Then how can I use or access this variable in another way? Can any one have idea? Please help me to get proper solution...

For example:

```
public function __construct() {
        $this->user = new User();;
}
```

How can we defined this?

Comment: Please show your class.

Comment: you are confusing what type of constructor is depreciated

Comment: see http://php.net/manual/ro/migration70.deprecated.php

Comment: What you mean `how can I use or access this variable` ?

Comment: What is the actual error PHP gives you, HOW can I reproduce your error? You have 2 `;`.

Answer (score 5):

The constructor function `__construct()` is not deprecated in PHP7.
This function is fired on the object creation.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php

> Classes which have a constructor method call this method on each
>   newly-created object, so it is suitable for any initialization that
>   the object may need before it is used.

Example:

```
<?php
class FooClass {
   function __construct() {
       echo "In FooClass constructor";
   }
}

$foo = new FooClass();
```

PHP4 style constructors (methods that have the same name as the class they're defined in) are deprecated.

Example:

```
<?php
class foo {
    function foo() {
        echo 'I am the constructor';
    }
}
?>
```

`foo` is a deprecated constructor in PHP7.